# why I can't concat two Single Android Room results with RxJava

Tags: observable, rx-java, android-room, concatenation

Why Single.concat(.., ..).toObservable() does not return only one observable to observe ?

I am working on search feature, on Android Room database, from different sources with same result type.

I want to show results in order from first source then second source.

```
@Query("SELECT id, title, from table1 where title LIKE :title  || '%'")
fun getItemsFirstTable(title: String): Single<List<MinimumResult>>

@Query("SELECT id, title, from table2 where title LIKE :title  || '%'")
fun getItemsSecondTable(title: String): Single<List<MinimumResult>>
```

method to concat Single and returns an Observable in view model

```
 public Observable<List<SearchItem>> concatSearchedItems(String s){
    return Single.concat(UseCaseKt.getItemsFirstTable(s), UseCaseKt.getItemsSecondTable(s)).toObservable()
}
```

bellow the TextWatcher

```
     Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Object> emitter) throws Exception {
            mEditTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    emitter.onNext(s.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext( l -> Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: "))
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap(new Function<Object, ObservableSource<List<SearchItem>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<List<SearchItem>> apply(Object o) throws Exception {
                    return searchViewModel.concatSearchedItems(o.toString());
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<SearchItem>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<SearchItem> searchItems) {
                    searchViewModel.searchList.setValue(searchItems);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

After debugging I found that onNext is called twice despite I already concat Single results.

Comment: So do you want to display List of 2 results like: [tab1result, tab2result], or do you want your Observable to emit 2 items: [tab2result] , [tab2result]?

Comment: yes I want to display the result list of both queries togther. Now onNext(...) is called twice and it returns each list sperated, I want to get merged list in onNext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Single.concat` does not concat data from emits of Singles, but concat Singles it self. 
So you need to use [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) :

```
public Observable<List<SearchItem>> concatSearchedItems(String s){
    return Singles.zip(UseCaseKt.getItemsFirstTable(s), UseCaseKt.getItemsSecondTable(s))
        { tab1list, tab2list -> listOf<SearchItem>().plus(tab1list).plus(tab2list) }
        .toObservable()
}
```